# how to get pairs of elements efficiently in a linked list (Haxe)

Tags: list, haxe

I have a list of objects and I would like to return each possible unique pair of objects within this list. Is the following the most efficient way to do that in Haxe?

```
for (elem1 in my_list)
{
   for (elem2 in my_list)
   { 
      if (elem1 == elem2)
      {
         break;
      }
      trace(elem1, elem2);
   }
}
```

I would rather avoid the equality check if possible. The reason that I am not using arrays or vectors is that these lists will be added to/removed from very frequently and I have no need for index level access.

Comment: By efficiency, do you mean in _computational time_, _memory_, or both?  Can any given element appear more than once in the list?  What is type of the element in the list?  Are you restricted to a particular target?

Comment: In particular, I am worried about the efficiency of adding to and removing elements from the data structure and I am not particularly worried about memory efficiency (So computational time). In any case, I don't think that haxe arrays are contiguous on most platforms but I am likely wrong. What I would like is to be able to remove that silly equality operator that is using up unnecessary cpu cycles (since any check that is only true one in N times is pretty useless).

Comment: I wouldn't worry at all about that conditional jump (`if`), since it should be pretty easy for the cpu to predict it.  And target wise, `Array` and `Vector` should be generally faster than `List` (due to the implementation of List), and even than `haxe.ds.GenericStack` (due to less cache misses).  Most importantly though, can your list have repeated elements?

Comment: No the list cannot have repeated elements. I'm also not super worried about access time for the elements in the list since the operations which are performed each update will completely dwarf the access cost. That being said, you are probably wondering why I am worried about the if statement (if it is computationally insignificant); its not really a performance thing, I was just wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: So even if list are slow to iterate through and memory inefficient due to being made from arrays, I think that they will be faster in this application simply due to the amount of elements that will be added and removed at run time. I will test this out though.

Comment: I see...  Well, you'll really need to test which is faster: `Array`, `List` or `GenericStack`.  Also, consider the surrounding code and make sure you're not causing to many conversions elsewhere, or making some API too horrible to use.

Comment: Ok so here are the results of a few tests:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to efficient (the less amount of iterations), you could loop like this:

```
for (i in 0 ... my_list.length-1) // loop to total minus 1
  for (j in i+1 ... my_list.length) // start 1 further than i, loop to end
    if (my_list[i] != my_list[j]) // not match
       [my_list[i], my_list[j]]]; // make pair
```

Btw, it depends on the content if linked list or array actually faster, since this uses indexes now. You should test/measure it your case (don't assume anything if it's performance critic piece of code).

**try online**:
http://try.haxe.org/#2Ab3F

Comment: If you were going to do that just loop i from 0 to length and j from 0 to i. Then you don't need any check. If you wanted all others except identical pairs, just add another loop after that loops j from i+1 to length

Comment: I don't think that the explicit conditional is needed.  If the list can't have repeated elements (as @Graham has now clarified), it seems unnecessary; in the other case, it still [fails](http://try.haxe.org/#b1A71) to produce _unique_ pairs.

Comment: I'm not sure if the question is to create a array with undoubled combinations, or to get all unique combinations out of the list. In any case this loop takes less iterations than the given example.